# Adding rows in a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

A user inputs a desired array of desired `rows` and `columns` . The code needs to look through the array and find all the rows with at least one negative number. If found , then the code adds a new row of `zeros` below the founded row.

> Code

```
#include <pch.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int rows, columns;
std::cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
std::cin >> rows;
std::cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
std::cin >> columns;


int **array = new int*[rows];                  //Generating a 2-D array
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    array[i] = new int[columns];

std::cout << "Enter the elements" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)              //loop for input array 
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)             //elements
        std::cin >> array[i][j];

for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {            //print the array
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {             //finding rows with negative
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {            //numbers and adding a new 
        if (array[i] < 0) {                     // row of zeros below
            array[i + 1][j] = 0;
            std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

return 0;
}
```

For instance
If we enter an array like
`1 1 1 1 1

2 -2 2 -2 2

3 3 3 3 3

4 -4 -4 4 4

5 5 5 5 5`
The answer should be
`1 1 1 1 1

2 -2 2 -2 2

0 0 0 0 0   -----> new rows added

3 3 3 3 3

4 -4 -4 4 4  ------> new rows added

0 0 0 0 0

5 5 5 5 5`
But my code doesn't do it ?

Comment: You array is not dimensionned to accept that. Can you use a vector of vectors ?

Comment: No, we aren't into vectors yet . This problem needs to be solved this way some how .

Comment: @Damien What does it mean , my array isn't dimensioned yet?

Comment: @J.Doe You will need to allocate for the new row, reallocate for the array of pointers, and then perform some memory moving in the array of pointers to insert it at the correct position. If you are supposed to learn c++, then this should not be done manually but with `std::vector`. If you are not allowed to use it then I would say the teacher should be teaching C instead of C++.

Comment: The number of rows increases. You need to overdimension the array. Moreover you have to increase `row` when a new line is added.

Comment: like `i++` or `rows++` ?

Comment: For example. Pay attention it is always dangerous to modify in a loop the variables that serve to control the loop. I meant that the array is not dimensioned at the good size.

Answer (score 0):

This main.cpp produces the desired output plus some monitoring.

Behold, the resulting array, including rows of zeroes where appropriate, is just written to stdout.  However, I have allocated twice as much space for the original array as this solution currently needs.

You could prop-up this solution to make in-place rewrites to the big array to contain the complete output array in its upper portion, if the need arises.

The program left as-is otherwise, half the array's size (1x rows times 1x columns) would suffice.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // The **wished for** array dimensions.
    int rows{0}, columns{0};

    std::cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
    std::cin  >>  rows;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
    std::cin  >>  columns;

    // ------------------------------------------------- ALLOCATION START ----

    // Generating 2-D array.
    int ** array = new int* [2 * rows];  // (*)

    // (*) Suppose all the rows are bad, i. e., with some negative number(s),
    //     then **each and every** single row had to be followd by zeroes.

    // Allocating the columns.
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * rows; i++) {
        array[i] = new int[columns];
    }


    // NEW --- NEW ---- NEW

    // Allocate bool array indicating that row[i] must be followed by zeroes. 
    bool* want_zeroes = new bool[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) want_zeroes[i] = false;     // Initialize

    // ----------------------------------------------- ALLOCATION END -----

    std::cout << "-- -- -- -- \n";

    // --------------------------------------------------- INTAKE START ---

    std::cout << "Enter the elements" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)              //loop for input array 
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)             //elements
            std::cin >> array[i][j];

    std::cout << "-- -- -- -- \n";

    std::cout << "Print the elements" << std::endl;

    // Monitor original array.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------- INTAKE END -------

    std::cout << "-- -- -- -- \n";

    // --------------------------------------------------- CHECK START ----

    std::cout << "Print want_zeroes" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {             //finding rows with negative
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {            //numbers and adding a new 

            // Check for negative element.
            if (array[i][j] < 0) {

                // Boom, found a bad row!
                // So, this is row so-and-so,
                // which needs to be followed
                // by a row of zeroes later.

                want_zeroes[i] = true;
            }
        }

        // Monitor.
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << want_zeroes[i] << '\n';
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------- CHECK END ------

    std::cout << "-- -- -- -- \n";

    // -------------------------------------- CONSTRUCT OUTPUT START -----

    // We use the quick-and-dirty solution, not modifying the original
    // array, but just outputting the solution to stdout, see if it's ok.

    std::cout << "Print resulting array" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

        // Output current original row anyway. 
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            std::cout << array[i][j] << ' ';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';

        // Was this a bad row?
        if (want_zeroes[i]) {

            // Yes! -- Output a row of zeroes.
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                std::cout << 0 << ' ';
            }

            std::cout << '\n';
        }
     }

    // -------------------------------------- CONSTRUCT OUTPUT END -------


    // ------------------------------------------ DEALLOCATION START -----

    // Dealocate want_zerores.
    if (want_zeroes != nullptr) {
        delete[] want_zeroes;
        want_zeroes  = nullptr;
    }


    // Deallocate the array's columns.
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * rows; i++) {
        if (array[i] != nullptr) {
            delete[] array[i];
            array[i]  = nullptr;
        }
    }

    // Dealocate array.
    if (array != nullptr) {
        delete[] array;
        array  = nullptr;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------- DEALLOCATION END -------

    return 0;
}
```

Regards, Micha